mp3などで音量の最大値が0.0dBまでしか存在しないのはなぜですか
デジタルファイルの音量調整をffmpegなどを制御する方法で行うつもりで調べていたところ、

音量の最大値を0.0dBとし、マイナス領域に進むにつれて音が小さくなる

という仕様を読みました。
実際にffmpegにファイルを読み込ませて最大音量を確認すると、最大で0.0dBとなっており、一部はそれ以下の値が最大値として設定されていました。
なぜマイナス域で音量を表現するのか理屈を教えていただけますか。
これがゼロを最小としてプラス域で表現してはいけない理屈を教えていただけますか。
0.0dB ～ Inf dBとした場合の問題
Infに寄るにつれて機材が音を再現できなくなり、最終的に音が飛んでブツ切れになるから
-Inf ～ 0.0dBとした場合
最小の音がブツ切れになっても人間が知覚できないから
この認識でいいでしょうか。

この辺の記事に書いてある内容とかを起点に検索を続けてみてはどうでしょう？ 最大値は0“ゼロ”, 【連載】デシベルの話（DTMer向け）#2, 【dBとLUFS】音量を揃える音量とラウドネスの基礎知識, オーディオレベルの概要

kunif様：返信遅れてすみません。いただいたリンクの１つ目がかなりわかりやすかったです。回答いただきました方の内容も読ませていただきなんとか理解に至りました。どうもありがとうございました。

dB って定義上は無次元量なので「絶対的な基準値」は存在しないわけです。なので基準をどこにとっても問題ないので、適宜便利なように選べばいいのです。
デジタルオーディオシステムにおいては Wikipedia の dB 解説 dB(fs) にも書いてあるわけですが
オーディオシステムの実用上は出してよい最大音量ってのはユーザーが決めたいわけです。野外音楽堂におけるコンサート時の最大音量と電車内での耳うどんで出してよい最大音量ってのは違います。なので「出してよい最大音量はユーザーによって違う」だろうが、音楽編集者（ミキサー）としては「その最大音量を基準にして相対的にどこまで音量を出してよいか」があると便利です。 dB はゲイン＝相対量を表すものなのですから、最大値を基準にどれだけ小さくしてよいか、を表現するなら必然的に 0dB(FS) がその最大値、小さくなる方向には dB(FS) 値としては負の値を使う、となります。

Infに寄るにつれて機材が音を再現できなくなり、最終的に音が飛んでブツ切れになるから

もし「オーディオシステムで」 +Inf が実現できるとしたら、それは無制限に大きな音となるわけです。最終的には音響爆弾ですよね？　そんなものが扱えてもリスナもミキサーも誰一人としてうれしくない、というかそもそも物理的に無限に大きな音が出せるオーディオシステムって実現不能です。そういう単位系には使い道がないです。

最小の音がブツ切れになっても人間が知覚できないから

単位系としてこういうシステムを選んだ理由としては No
この文言だけ取れば、結果論として Yes (耳の良い人と悪い人でその下限値は違うだろうが）

774RR様：返信遅れてすみません細かい解説までいただき理解に至りました。ありがとうございます。いわれてみれば再生する所在（会場やイヤホンなど）はあくまで実出力ですが曲などのデータはその中でのみ音の強弱がありますね。どうもありがとうございました。


最大で0.0dBとなっており、一部はそれ以下の値が最大値として設定されていました。
なぜマイナス域で音量を表現するのか理屈を教えていただけますか。

私もどうしてだろうと思った側なのですが、私の考えとしては、最大を 0 として扱った方が利便性が良いからではないでしょうか？
例えば、音源が小さい音で録音されているとして、その音源の全体の音量を上げたいととき、最大の音量の場所を 0 として、相対的に全体の音量を上げる方が、容易だと思います。
最小を 0 として、下限を合わせることは、あまりないのかと。
また、複数の音源のレベル感を合わせる場合もピークを 0 として合わせた方が、音源間の整合性がとれるのではないでしょうか？
ノーマライズする際に、ピーク値を 0 とした方が都合が良いからだと考えました。
ノーマライズについては、以下に説明があります。

https://dtmhacker.com/normalize-basic/


hiromasa masuda様：ご回答ありがとうございます。ミキシング作業などで各サウンドの音量制御などの操作性において、ご回答のように制御の易さを感じていました。納得しました。どうもありがとうございました。
